# Invert a dictionary with list values in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-facts

How do I convert a dictionary like below

```
{
"host1": ["tag1", "tag2"],
"host2": ["tag1"]
}
```

to below in ansible:

```
{
"tag1": ["host1","host2"],
"tag2": ["host1"]
}
```

I have been trying to do this but got stuck due to the value being a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    dict1:
      host1: [tag1, tag2]
      host2: [tag1]
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        dict2: "{{ dict2|default({})|combine({item: list_of_hosts}) }}"
      loop: "{{ dict1.values()|flatten|unique }}"
      vars:
        list_of_hosts: "{{ dict1|
                           dict2items|
                           selectattr('value', 'contains', item)|
                           map(attribute='key')|
                           list }}"
    - debug:
        var: dict2
```

gives

```yaml
  dict2:
    tag1: [host1, host2]
    tag2: [host1]
```

---

Optionally, use *json_query*

```yaml
      vars:
        list_of_hosts: "{{ dict1|dict2items|json_query(_query) }}"
        _query: '[?value.contains(@, `{{ item }}`)].key'
```